# How to reply to a message using Gerrit REST?

Tags: rest, gerrit

I am trying to use Gerrit's REST Api to post a message to an existing review, and then **reply** to the same message, similar to the `REPLY` button that exists on the web version of Gerrit.
Running the following command:

```
curl -u USERNAME:PASS -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" gerrit-server.com/a/changes/If875a8dc754b911098b0746d9ac47b332bee64d1/revisions/current/review -X POST -d '{"message" : "This is a message"}'
```

Posts a message [image]

Then, GETting the `messages` via REST yields the following:

```
{"id":"75315257818648484913e5ae8a5486df3ba36093","author":{"_account_id":1001115,"name":"Itzhaki","email":"itzhaki@email.com","username":"itzhaki"},"real_author":{"_account_id":1001115,"name":"Itzhaki","email":"itzhaki@email.com","username":"itzhaki"},"date":"2023-10-01 10:22:22.000000000","message":"Patch Set 1:\n\nThis is a message","accounts_in_message":[],"_revision_number":1}
```

Using the Web UI I can post a reply, and then fetch replies via the `revisions/current/comments` call:

```
{"author":{"_account_id":1001115,"name":"itzhaki","email":"itzhaki@email.com","username":"itzhaki"},"unresolved":false,"id":"c467be8a_5ba9ae1c","updated":"2023-10-01 10:28:07.000000000","message":"\u003e Patch Set 1:\n\u003e \n\u003e This is a message\n\nThe is a reply from the web","commit_id":"7bc692141fdc2de88091d64c226e1bdf3b13bc7a"}
```

[image]
However I can't find the relation between the reply comment and the original message, nor do I know how to do so with REST.

How do I post a reply to `75315257818648484913e5ae8a5486df3ba36093` via REST?